# sinon stub nested in describe / request function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sinon, supertest

I've got a fairly simple test using Mocha, Sinon and SuperTest:

```
describe('POST /account/register', function(done) {

    beforeEach(function(done) {
        this.accountToPost = {
            firstName: 'Alex',
            lastName: 'Brown',
            email: 'a@b.com',
            password: 'password123'
        };

        this.email = require('../../app/helpers/email');
        sinon.stub(this.email, 'sendOne')

        done();
    });

    afterEach(function(done){
        this.email.sendOne.restore();
        done();
    })

    it('sends welcome email', function(done) {

        request(app)
            .post('/account/register')
            .send(this.accountToPost)
            .expect(200)
            .end(function(err, res) {
                should.not.exist(err)

                //this line is failing
                assert(this.email.sendOne.calledWith('welcome'));

                done();
            });
    });
});
```

The issue I'm having is when I `assert(this.email.sendOne.calledWith('welcome'))` - this.email is undefined.
I'm pretty sure this is because this isn't the scope I was expecting - i think this is now the scope of the request.end?

How can I get to my sinon stub to assert that function was called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your test so that you grab the value of `this` where you know that it has the value you want to use later and assign it to a variable that you can then use in the inner scope (`test` in the example below) then refer to your test with that variable:

```
it('sends welcome email', function(done) {
    var test = this;
    request(app)
        .post('/account/register')
        .send(this.accountToPost)
        .expect(200)
        .end(function(err, res) {
            should.not.exist(err)

            assert(test.email.sendOne.calledWith('welcome'));

            done();
        });
});
```

Another way to avoid this is to not set values on the mocha test objects themselves but to make them variable in the closure formed by the callback passed to `describe` or some other appropriate closure. I can't help noticing that in the examples on the main [mocha page](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/), none of them assign anything to `this`.  A good example from that page:

```
describe('Connection', function(){
  var db = new Connection
    , tobi = new User('tobi')
    , loki = new User('loki')
    , jane = new User('jane');

  beforeEach(function(done){
    db.clear(function(err){
      if (err) return done(err);
      db.save([tobi, loki, jane], done);
    });
  })

  describe('#find()', function(){
    it('respond with matching records', function(done){
      db.find({ type: 'User' }, function(err, res){
        if (err) return done(err);
        res.should.have.length(3);
        done();
      })
    })
  })
})
```

This is how I do it myself, to avoid the possibility of a name clash with mocha's internals.